# Minimal surface having a Jordan curve as boundary

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds, surfaces, plane-curves, minimal-surfaces

I'm trying to prove that if $\gamma$ is a Jordan curve (contained in the plane $\pi$) and $\Sigma\subset\mathbb{R}^3$ is a minimal surface with $\partial\Sigma=\gamma$, then $\Sigma$ must be the plane region $\Omega\subset\pi$ in $\pi$ delimited by $\gamma$.

It's clear that, if $\Sigma$ can be represented as a graph $u:\Omega\to\mathbb{R}$, then the only way to minimize the area is to chose $u\equiv 0$, so that $\Sigma=\Omega$.

But in the general case, I don't know how to justify it. I'm trying to use the maximum principle, but I don't know how.

Any tips?

Comment: Suggestion: Start by letting $z$ be a Cartesian coordinate "orthogonal to" the plane containing $\gamma$, and show the absolute extrema of $z$ are both $0$.

Comment: @RafaelGonzalezLopez: I'm confused by your question. Are you suggesting the sphere has mean curvature $0$? ... To the OP: Remember, however, that minimal surfaces needn't be area-minimizing!

Comment: @TedShifrin Sorry, I was mistaked thiking about Plateau's problem.

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang, here is what I'm thinking: if there is a maximum $z=M>0$, then $\Sigma$ is contained in one side of the plane $\{z=M\}$ and $\Sigma\cap\{z=M\}\neq \emptyset$, so $\Sigma=\{z=M\}$ (absurd), same as for the minimum. So if there is a maximum and a minimum, they must be zero. Does that make sense?

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang in any case, how can I justify that the extrema are not $\infty$ and $-\infty$?

Comment: You will need a compactness assumption, since otherwise a truncated catenoid provides a counterexample.